# Game Analysis Software

Tags: engines, analysis

### What I need

Is there any software/engine/website (preferably free) that can analyze a given game (or PGN) of mine and tell me:

- Whether my moves were excellent, good, bad or terrible.
- Possible variations at different positions.
- Reasons why a **bad move** was bad, and suggestions for a better move.

### What I found

The thing I found closest to that is the **computer analysis** option on Chess.com , which tells me how many of my (and my opponent's) moves were good, bad and awful, and also suggests better moves in place of my errors. However, despite being rather good, it seems (to me) that it analyzes only the games I play on the site.

#### Any suggestions?

Comment: You can import your own game into chess.com.

Comment: @SmallChess What do you mean by human-like annotation?

Comment: @SmallChess And thanks, I didn't know one could import one's games to Chess.com!

Comment: Are you willing to pay for such software/engine/service? Are you looking for a free service?

Comment: @Yaron Preferably it should be free. I'll edit my question!

Comment: LiChess.org is free and easy, but you have to register.  Almost every interface can give you what the computer thinks is best.  There was one which displayed the difference between the played move and the best move, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Does Stockfish do this? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @FredKnight Would be glad if you could find that interface! Thanks for the advice on LiChess.com!

Comment: @AricFowler SF is an engine, it doesn't tell you about blunders. You need a GUI.

Comment: @SmallChess , I use Arena (with Stockfish as engine​) as a GUI, and I don't know how to use it for analysis or use it as described in the question. Could you give me some advice on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LiChess.org is free and easy, but you have to register. Almost every interface can give you what the computer thinks is best.

http://www-lucaschess.rhcloud.com/ is a good program for beginners, but at more advanced levels the computer seems to hang.
Lucas chess has a game analysis.[image]

The output shows current evaluation, best move, your score relative to the best score, and, under indexes, average centipawn loss with other stats.

The program comes with many adjustable parameters.  The main problem, other the the hanging engine, is that it is difficult to find which function you want.  They do have links to many videos showing how to use their program.

If after watching the videos you still have problems, we could start a thread about this problem.

Comment: Thanks, @FredKnight ! I will check out the sites you suggested and let you know of my thoughts! (+1)

Comment: Just FYI: You don't need to be registered to use the LiChess analyzing tools. You can enter it directly here: https://lichess.org/analysis

Answer (score 2):

The old Fritz 5.32 was (and still is free). You can download it from here http://freechess.50webs.com/fritz.html. You will probably need to have Windows 7 and run in compatibility mode for XP to get this old program to run but it is still quite powerful.

If you want free chess software then http://freechess.50webs.com/index.html is an excellent place to start.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianTowers! I will check them out and see how they work!(+1)

Answer (score 1):

I find [stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) pretty good.

Runs on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Stockfish / Droidfish: just put the PGN files that you download to the file of Droidfish PGN. You can view and analyze games .. you can download PGN files in pgnmentor for a specific opening or specific player.